# Assembler: In edi-register stored value changes. Why?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written this assembly program:

```
start:
    call read_hex

    mov edi, eax ; edi stores the limit.
    mov esi, 0 ; esi stores the counting variable.
loopBody:
    inc esi
    mov eax, esi
    call print_eax
    mov eax, edi
    call print_eax
    cmp edi, esi
    JE finishUp

    call read_hex
    add ebx, eax

    JMP loopBody

finishUp:
    mov eax, edi
    call print_eax
    push    0
    call    [ExitProcess]
```

The belonging assignment is:

> Write a program that takes the value m as input. It then receives m
>         consecutive numbers from the user, sums all those numbers and prints back the total sum to the console.

See assignment 0.1: https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/0_branching/2_basic_conditional_branching/ex/2_write_code/write_code.txt

My idea is to store the limit the user have entered into edi.

esi is used as the counting variable.

Now let's say I have entered 3 as the limit (It shall count three consecutive numbers). 0 is what I enter as input every time when the next number is expected.

I get the following result:

[image]

The first time passing through the loop everything is expected.

esi is 1 and edi is 3.

But next loop passthrough the value of edi has changed to 6ff7b !!

**Why has edi changed it's value?**

I haven't touched it nowhere!

Comment: What are `read_hex` and `print_eax`? Are they guaranteed to preserve register values?

Comment: These two functions are provided by the tutor. Because reading and writing to stdout and stdin is a bit hard for a beginner.

Comment: The code of read_hex and print_eax :https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/include/training.inc

Comment: Functions are allowed to destroy the contents of certain registers. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for details.

Comment: Okay. The question is solved. edx is changed in read_hex. I haven't thought about that possibility myself. Sorry.

Comment: Post this as an answer to your own question so future readers know.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was caused by the included function "read_hex".

The code of "read_hex" can be seen here:

https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/include/training.inc

edi is changed multiple times within the function. And by that was caused the unexpected behaviour.

So therefore to all other assembler beginners:

Be careful when including code from someone else. Remember that it can change your program's state.

Comment: Keep in mind the CPU registers are "global" in the most global sense possible (per single core).

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Coming from high-level languages, with features like private properties etc., that was a valuable lesson to me. :)) Thank you for pointing out the issue precisely.

Comment: This is why we have calling conventions, so that functions can agree on which registers can be clobbered by a function call and which must be preserved.  (Of course, asm code can do whatever it wants, instead of following any of the standard calling conventions.)  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to ABI docs (which include calling conventions), and also the basic stuff about calling conventions [on SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions).  EDI is preserved across calls in the usual 32-bit calling conventions, so that's non-standard.